# Copiar VARIOS campos de una tabla a UN campo de otra en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenos dias recien me registro y en primer lugar quiero agradecer la predisposición por parte de esta comunidad para responder a las cuestiones de los que menos sabemos. Lo que necesito es si alguien me puede ayudar informándome si es posible copiar uno o mas campos de una tabla a un único campo de otra tabla. La idea es que cuando cambie un campo de un registro de una tabla, se generen en la tabla de destino tantos registros como campos cambiados. La finalidad de la tabla destino es especificamente registrar el histórico de cambios de un registro en la tabla origen.--- Les agradecería si me pueden ilustrar con un ejemplo.--- Soy bastante novato en mysql, pero muy autodidacta. Desde ya AGRADECIDO!

```
if ALTER TABLE Tabla1(campo1, campo2,...) INSERT INTO Tabla2.campo1
```

No se si me explico.---

Comment: Poné algo de código para que te puedan ayudar mejor. Saludos

Comment: Asi es... perdon por no expresarme con términos más técnicos. Quisiera un log, pero que en el log solo se copie el campo cambiado de la tabla origen a la tabla destino. Obviamente se tratan de campos con el mismo tipo de dato.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Trata de ser mas claro con lo que necesitas, agregar que intentaste hasta ahora, donde fallo y poner algun ejemplo de lo que necesitas. No se puede hacer un if alter table, porque alter table se usa para cambiar la estructura de una tabala

Comment: No soy experto en BD's, y tengo entendido que pueden hacerse trigers o disparadores que detecten esos cambios y ejecuten X acción, deberías investigar sobre el tema, si estás usando un lenguaje , ej php  lo que podrías hacer es que en cada Update que hagas en la Bd hagas una inserción en la tabla registro , tal vez esto te sirva (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152974/fire-a-trigger-after-the-update-of-specific-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: gbianchi gracias por las sugerencias... ofrezco disculpas nuevamente, soy nuevo en foros, de hecho este es el primero en el que participo activamente.--- ya voy a aprender :)

Comment: Andress Blend gracias por responder. Estuve leyendo sobre la implementacion de triggers con phpmyadmin pero lo he encontrado muy confuso. A lo mejor soy demasiado novato.--- Voy a seguir investigando.

Comment: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f86/detectar-cambios-precisos-realizados-1-registro-por-medio-trigger-1122848/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

si no entendi mal,por lo que lei en los comentarios, vos estas intentando obtener un log. para eso tendrias que crear un Trigger.

El trigger puede resultar complicado de enterder si se tiene poca experiencia en DB's.

Lo que hay que entender en practica, es que el Trigger define la accion que el database tiene que ejercer quando se verifica un evento.

Trigger a nivel de linea : este trigger viene ejecutado una sola vez por linea(row) por cada instruccion DML. viene declarada en la creacion del trigger indicando la clausula "for each row".

Trigger a nivel de institucion: viene ejecutado una sola vez por accion DML, ej : haces un insert de 20 lineas, el trigger a nivel institucional entra en fucion solo una vez y no 20, por eso este tipo de nivel no viene utilizado muy frecuentemente.

**BEFORE y AFTER** 
Este atributo le dice al trigger cuando tiene que empezar a trabajar.

before : se ejecuta antes del codigo DML, se utiliza usualmente para la normalizacion de los dato insertados, es decir, agregas una linea y en el nombre pones algo como : "pLUTO" pero el nombre lo queres con la mayuscula inicial, si utilizas el before, podes modificar el dato y normalizarlo :"Pluto" antes que este sea insertado en el database.

after: se ejecuta despues del codigo DML, este se utiliza usualmente para crear logs.

**como crear un trigger :**

```
create [or replace] trigger [nombre del trigger]
[before | after] [update | delete | insert] on [tabla de origen]
[clausula] // es decir for each row, ya que es a nivel instutucional de default
begin
   //tu codigo 
   // aca harias el insert en la tabla de destino
   // si se utiliza el trigger After update (el que te sirve para el log)
   // para alcanzar los datos y ver los cambios tendrias que hace de la siguente manera: 
   //:old.nombreCampo  para obtener el dato antes de la modifica y
   //:new.nombreCampo para obtener el dato despues de la modifica, osea el valor actual.
end;
```

espero que esto te pueda servir de ayuda ☺

Comment: Muchas gracias Federico. Excelente tu explicación.---

Comment: @dieWalever si la respuesta te fue util para solucionar el problema, votala como respuesta correcta, en caso haya otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema